# The transpose operator on $M_{2 \times 2}$ is orthogonal with respect to the inner product $A \cdot B = \textrm{trace}(A^T B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

> In each of the following given are an inner product space $(V,\cdot)$ and a linear operator $T : V → V$.
>
> Is $T$ symmetric? If the operator is symmetric, find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $T$.
>
> (a) For $M_{2\times 2}$ with $A \cdot B = \textrm{trace}(A^T B)$, let $T(A)=A^T$.

I know that an operator T is symmetric if $u \cdot T(v) = T(u) \cdot v$ for all $u$ and $v$. This is also equivalent to this equality holding for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in some orthonormal basis, and also to $M_B(T)$ being symmetric for some orthonormal basis. But I am not really sure what after.

Comment: You need to edit your formatting. What is $u\cdot T$ squarebox squarebox $v$?

Comment: I've attempted to format the original question using LaTeX. @Flow Please ensure that I've preserved your intended notation/meaning.

Comment: As for the mathematics, what happens if one compares $u \cdot T(v)$ and $T(u) \cdot v$ for this $V$ and $\cdot$?

Comment: @Travis thank you so much for that! that is perfect! I have just started  learning LaTeX. That is why I didnt write it like you.

Comment: @Flow: I recommend browsing this helpful reference, which is partly specific to MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Travis is one compares those two  they should be equal and therfore T is symmetric

Comment: That resolves the question then, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to check that
$$
T(A)\bullet B=\operatorname{trace}(AB)
$$
and that
$$
A\bullet T(B)=\operatorname{trace}(A^TB^T)=\operatorname{trace}((BA)^T)
$$
Can you end the check?

Hints: $\operatorname{trace}(C)=\operatorname{trace}(C^T)$; $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\operatorname{trace}(BA)$.

---

If $A$ is an eigenvector for $T$, then $A^T=\lambda A$, for some $\lambda$. Thus $a_{ji}=\lambda a_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ (with I hope obvious notation).

In particular $a_{ij}=\lambda a_{ji}=\lambda^2 a_{ij}$, hence
$$
(1-\lambda^2)a_{ij}=0
$$
for all $i,j$. Since $A$ is nonzero, this implies $\lambda=\pm1$.

Can you go on?

Hint: an eigenvector is either a symmetric or an antisymmetric matrix.

Comment: I am having a really hard time trying to see how to solve this.

Comment: @Flow I added some further hints